# My WHILE loop to display videos from mysql table is not working. What am I missing?

Tags: php

I am working on a large project and ran into a problem where I can only display one video from a table of several videos. The first video displays correctly, but the WHILE loop to display the additional videos does not produce any result and seems to end the PHP code altogether.

I have removed all non-essential elements of the code I am currently working on with the exception of comments. Similar code is working elsewhere in my project for images, but this code will not seem to work when displaying videos.

```
<?php
include_once '../includes/db_connect.php';      //  THIS CONNECTS THE DATABASE
include_once '../includes/functions.php';       //  THIS PROVIDES VARIOUS FUNCTIONS     
sec_session_start();                         

// THIS ENABLES ERROR MESSAGE DISPLAY //
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

// THIS QUERIES ALL COLUMNS FROM THE 'VIDEOS' TABLE //
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM videos");  
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

    // THESE TWO LINES WILL DISPLAY THE FIRST VIDEO IN THE TABLE //
    echo "<br><br>" . $result['name'] . "<br>";
    echo "<video src='" . $result['location'] . "' controls width='320px' height='200px' >";


while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) 
{
    // THIS SHOULD DISPLAY THE VAR_DUMP INFORMATION //
    echo "<br> ******************** TROUBLESHOOTING INFORMATION ********************** <br>";
    var_dump($result);                          // THIS IS JUST FOR DIAGNOSTIC INFO //
    echo "<br> ***************************************************************************** <br>";

    // THIS SHOULD DISPLAY THE REMAINING 2 VIDEOS IN THE TABLE AS ABOVE //
    echo "<br><br>" . $result['name'] . "<br>";
    echo "<video src='" . $result['location'] . "' controls width='320px' height='200px' >";
}
```

The code should display 3 small video images with controls to play the each video. The first video displays correctly so the database is connected, the table is being read correctly, and the commands to display the video are all working, but the WHILE loop is not working. I believe something in the video display line is causing the PHP code to quit but I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: Is _anything_ from the `while` loop being output?

Comment: Additionally, the var_dump command above is not displaying output UNLESS I remove the 2 lines to display the first video. If I remove the 2 lines to display the first video then the var_dump info is displayed and the second video is displayed, but not the third video, etc.

Comment: One loop should display *all* of the videos. You shouldn't have to fetch twice. `mysqli_fetch_array()` fetches everything*. What you want is `mysqli_fetch_row()`

Comment: Once the first video is displayed the code seems to quit and nothing further is displayed and the var_dump doesn't output anything. If I remove the 2 lines for the first video the var_dump will display only the information for the second video, nothing for the third video.

Comment: When you say "displayed", are you talking about the raw HTML source or what actually gets rendered on the page?

Comment: you're not closing the `<video>` element, the additional results are inside it. view the source in your browser

Comment: @andrew, Thank You, that is the solution. I failed to close the video element, which was causing the problem. Your assistance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One loop should display all of the videos. You shouldn't have to fetch twice.

```
/ THIS QUERIES ALL COLUMNS FROM THE 'VIDEOS' TABLE //
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM videos");  

while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) 
{

    // THIS SHOULD DISPLAY ALL ROWS //
    echo "<br><br>" . $result['name'] . "<br>";
    echo "<video src='" . $result['location'] . "' controls width='320px' height='200px' ></video></br>";
}
```

In addition, you need to close the `</video>` tag on each row.

Comment: @Marvin, indeed, `mysqli_fetch_all` gets all rows